# How to post array in object Angular 8

Tags: angular

I have a problem in my code that when I create a new user, every user has a role.

*This JSON in Swagger*

```
{
  "userName": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "surname": "string",
  "emailAddress": "string",
  "isActive": true,
  "roleNames": [
    "string" <----- cannot post this
  ],
  "password": "string"
}
```

*This My ts*

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {
    'roleNames': [
      'Admin'
    ],
  };
  PostUser() {
    this.adminService.PostUser(this.model).subscribe(res => {
      this.toastr.success('Tambah Data Berhasil !');
      this.adminService.RedirectBack();
    }, error => {
      this.saving = false;
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

*This my Service*

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('zJhbIsIIeyInCI6iOR5Gc1NicJIUkpXVCJ9'),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {

  PostUser(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'services/app/User/Create', model, httpOptions);
  }


}
```

*This My HTML*

```
<form #postUser="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="PostUser(postUser)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span for="userName">Username</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Username"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.userName" #userName="ngModel" autocomplete="off"required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span for="name">Nama</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nama"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.name" #name="ngModel" autocomplete="off"required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span for="surname">Surname</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Surname"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.surname" #surname="ngModel" autocomplete="off"required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span for="emailAddress">Email</span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.emailAddress" #emailAddress="ngModel" autocomplete="off" required>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span for="roleNames">Role</span>
                <select class="form-control" name="roleNames" id="roleNames" placeholder="Role"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.roleNames" autocomplete="off" required>
                    <option *ngFor="let roles of roles" value="{{roles.name}}">{{roles.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span for="password">Password</span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button [disabled]="saving" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-3">Tambah</button>
        <button [disabled]="saving" type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="RedirectBack()">Kembali</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

my problem is when I want to select a user role in the select option

I have tried several ways but have not found a solution.

Thank you, hopefully anyone can help me.

Comment: What's the output ? Where did you declare `httpOptions` ?

Comment: Can you explain your problem in detail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to provide the html code, so I saved the role data in the select option, the results of my code were successfully input but I couldn't change the other roles, because I saved the default value in the model, I declared httpOptions in the service

Comment: In which model you are saving default value.

Comment: Here, in  my .ts ->  model: any = {
    'roleNames': [
      'Admin'
    ],
  };

Comment: There are 3 roles, user, admin and authorization.

Comment: ok, do u want to change the role according to backend data.

Comment: yeah right, I bound the role data in the select option

Comment: can you post *roles* data. <option *ngFor="let roles of roles"........

Comment: no, I can't post *role* data, my problem is there, can't post *role* data, so I fill in the manual in the model: any = {'roleNames': ['Admin'],};

Comment: {'roleNames': ['Admin'],};, this roleNames  is binded with ngModel. There is looping for the options, (<option *ngFor="let roles of roles"...).  Here roles has data that you are looping to specify in drop down list.

Comment: so do I have to delete the default Admin value in the {'roleNames' model: ['Admin'],}; here?

Comment: In .ts file, roleNames: any = 'Admin'

Comment: In .html file, [(ngModel)]="roleNames"